# How to import an already checked out svn repository into Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository

I have a Subversion repository I have checked out and have in my local hard disk. Now, how do I import this into Eclipse?

When I choose *File > Import* and choose SVN, there is only an option to checkout a project from the server again. *File > New* project seems to be for projects we are creating new projects from scratch.

Comment: You probably know this, but there's no restriction on the number 'working copies' you can make from a repository. There's no harm in checking out again (unless you're really concerned about bandwidth usage).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Import..." the existing project then "Share..." the project.  The Subversive (or SubClipse) client will realize that the project has a .svn folder and reattach to the repository.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse click on:

> File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace

However you have to define a workspace location being different from the one that is being checked out in order to prevent yourself from changes to the checked out repository.

Comment: As long as your default and preferred workspace has been set up and loaded, there's no problem when using the wizard. I tested it in Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2RC3).

Answer (score 1):

I've tried with `File->Import Projects from File System or Archive`, and in the blank space of `Import source`, you just need to browse through button `Directory..` and find the project path you wanted to import. Then the svn connection is automatically detected.

Answer (score 0):

Install the subversive plugin from market place or from update site.

Use appropriate SVN connectors during setup `Windows->Preferances->Team->SVN->SVNConnectors`. SVNKit 1.8.11 worked for me.

Make sure `Enable automatic project share` checkbox is set at this location `Windows->Preferances->Team->SVN->General`

Just import the existing SVN project `File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace`, then eclipse will automatically recognize it based on the `.svn` hidden folder. Need not explicitly do `Team->Share project`.