# Eclipse and SVN import a existing folder that has been SVN checked out

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository

I have a folder (it also has subfolders, containing many java files) on my local hard disk.
This folder was checked out from my svn repository.  I can do all the svn commands in that folder.

Now i am using Eclipse, is there a way for me to "import" that folder, and so that for all the changes I made in the Eclipse editor on those files will be reflected as well?

My question is same as [How to import an already checked out svn repository into Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699338/how-to-import-an-already-checked-out-svn-repository-into-eclipse)

BUT, the answer, I am not able to get, such as "import..." then "share...", can someone please elaborate these two steps?

If i do "import..." -> "General" -> "existing project"
BUT i don't get it, the folder i want to import is NOT an ECLIPSE PROJECT, so should i still go with this route?

or should I do "Import..." -> "General"-> "file system"? but it requires me to create a project first in eclipse, so i don't think i should go that path

here is what i awant to archive at the end
1. For the folder i want to import, i want to be able to do all the svn stuff, such as commit, update,etc
2. the file i edit in the eclipse, should be the same file in the folder i checked out from svn

please help....

Comment: I should add that in order for the "import..." -> "General" -> "existing project" to work, it seems it needs a .project file or the folder was an eclipse project....but again the folder i check out from repository are simply just folder with files, it wasn't an eclipse project or anything

Comment: Does your folder come with a Ant build.xml or Maven pom.xml when checked out from SVN?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. What I am testing now is creating a new general project and importing the file system. This is creating a duplicate of the 1gb repo, which isn't optimal. I'll post an answer if I figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

"import..." -> "General" -> "existing project" (Browse for the project which u have checked out into ur local hard disk)

then in that window down there is a checkbox to select "copy projects into workspace" => uncheck this option.

this will have project in Eclipse and local existing folder that has been SVN checked out where u can
1. For the folder u want to import, u want to be able to do all the svn stuff, such as commit, update,etc 
2. the file u edit in the eclipse, should be the same file in the folder u checked out from svn.

cheers.. this will work!!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has tried all of the suggestions dealing with importing projects and find that it still doesn't work, you may have a mis-configured connector.

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN -> SVN Connector.  Make sure the version of the SVN Connector matches the version of SVN you have checked out the code with.

For example, if your connector is configured for svn 1.7.x, and the source is checked out with 1.8.x, then Eclipse will not recognize your SVN repository.  If you don't have the right SVN Connector version installed and can't convince Eclipse to install it automatically, you might want to go to the [SVNKit web site](http://svnkit.com/download.php) for further instructions.

Once you have the proper SVN Connector specified, go back and try to Share Project (or Share Projects), or remove and re-import the existing projects.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to "import" a folder without .project-file:
File -> new -> Project... -> General -> Project

Then you have to chose the Location (untick "Use default location" and press the "Browse..." Button):
[image]

Press "Finish" and you get the Project in eclipse with SVN History. Also eclipse adds the ".project" file.